# WriteInternal not called in Common.Logging AbstractLogger derivative

Tags: c#, common.logging

I am trying to get Common.Logging to call my custom logger, but WriteInternal is never called. Did I miss a configuration somewhere? In my ASP.NET Owin project, Startup.cs has

```
        LogManager.Adapter = new HubLoggerAdapter(resolver.Kernel.Get<ILogger>());
```

where ILogger is my custom logger. HubLoggerAdapter looks like

```
public class HubLoggerAdapter : ILoggerFactoryAdapter
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public HubLoggerAdapter(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public ILog GetLogger(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        }

        try
        {
            return new HubLogger(_logger);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var x = ex.Message;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ILog GetLogger(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        try
        {
            return new HubLogger(_logger);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var x = ex.Message;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the logger looks like

```
public class HubLogger : AbstractLogger
{
    public override bool IsTraceEnabled { get { return _logLevel.HasFlag(LogLevel.Trace); } }
    public override bool IsDebugEnabled { get { return _logLevel.HasFlag(LogLevel.Debug); } }
    public override bool IsErrorEnabled { get { return _logLevel.HasFlag(LogLevel.Error); } }
    public override bool IsFatalEnabled { get { return _logLevel.HasFlag(LogLevel.Fatal); } }
    public override bool IsInfoEnabled { get { return _logLevel.HasFlag(LogLevel.Info); } }
    public override bool IsWarnEnabled { get { return _logLevel.HasFlag(LogLevel.Warn); } }

    private LogLevel _logLevel;
    private ILogger _logger;

    public HubLogger(ILogger logger)
        : this(logger, LogLevel.All)
    {

    }

    public HubLogger(ILogger logger, LogLevel level)
        : base()
    {            
        _logLevel = level;
        _logger = logger;

        _logger.Log("initiating HubLogger");
    }

    protected override void WriteInternal(LogLevel level, object message, Exception exception)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case LogLevel.All:
            case LogLevel.Trace:
            case LogLevel.Debug:
            case LogLevel.Info:
            case LogLevel.Warn:
            case LogLevel.Error:
                _logger.Log(message.ToString());
                if (exception != null)
                {
                    _logger.Log(exception);
                }
                break;
            case LogLevel.Off:
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("level", level, "invalid logging level");
        }
    }
}
```

If I call 
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger();
            logger.Warn("I'm alive.");

I see "initiating HubLogger" but then WriteInternal is never called for my message. It is really odd. Any insight much appreciated.

**Edit 1.** Tried to add constructor with NameValueCollection per suggestion, but it did not work. Specifically added

```
    private ILogger _logger;
    public IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    public HubLoggerAdapter(NameValueCollection props)
    {
```

//            _logger = props["logger"];
        }

```
    public HubLoggerAdapter(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

and used

```
        var props = new NameValueCollection();
        var adapter = new HubLoggerAdapter(props);
        adapter.Kernel = resolver.Kernel;
        LogManager.Adapter = adapter;
```

not sure why the constructor would make any difference.

Comment: http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/logging.html: 1.5.1: "Important: Any implementation must provide a public constructor accepting a NameValueCollection parameter"

Comment: I wonder how I can pass my object in there then.

Comment: and that is really odd too, don't we create it ourselves? I tried your suggestion, but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by deriving from AbstractSimpleLogger and AbstractSimpleLoggerFactoryAdapter.

```
public class HubLogger : AbstractSimpleLogger
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public HubLogger(ILogger logger, string logName, LogLevel logLevel, bool showLevel, bool showDateTime, bool showLogName, string dateTimeFormat)
        : base(logName, logLevel, showLevel, showDateTime, showLogName, dateTimeFormat)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override void WriteInternal(LogLevel level, object message, Exception e)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case LogLevel.All:
            case LogLevel.Trace:
            case LogLevel.Debug:
            case LogLevel.Info:
            case LogLevel.Warn:
            case LogLevel.Error:
                // Use a StringBuilder for better performance
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                FormatOutput(sb, level, message, e);

                if (e != null)
                {
                    _logger.Log(e);
                }
                _logger.Log(sb.ToString());
                break;
            case LogLevel.Off:
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("level", level, "invalid logging level");
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private ILogger _logger;

    public HubLoggerAdapter(ILogger logger)
        : base(null)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override ILog CreateLogger(string name, LogLevel level, bool showLevel, bool showDateTime, bool showLogName, string dateTimeFormat)
    {
        ILog log = new HubLogger(_logger, name, level, showLevel, showDateTime, showLogName, dateTimeFormat);
        return log;
    }
}
```